# mongodb + node connection string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having trouble connecting mongodb to my local machine. I'm new at this and can't seem to figure it out from the docs or other stackoverflow posts.

I have a database.js file, and I think my connection string is wrong:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost');
// I've tried this too:
// mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
// mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:8080/test');

module.exports = {
    'url' : 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'
}
```

I've got mongod running in one tab and shows 4 connections open - I don't know if it's this or the connection string.

Then in a 2nd tab, I've connected to a db called "test".

Lastly there's a very simple view. When I navigate to localhost:8080 (where process.env.PORT || 8080 is pointing to in server.js), it doesn't connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is configuration file

```
{
    "db": {
        "connection": "mongodb://localhost",
        "name": "testdb"             
    }
}
```

Here is usage in code:

```
var dbUrl = config.get('db:connection') + '/' + config.get('db:name');
var db = mongoose.connection;

mongoose.connect(dbUrl, function(err) {
 //your stuff here 
});
```

Hope, it helps.

P.S. Could you please provide how you catch no connection to db?

Comment: I was mistaken. I thought the server.js was running w/nodemon but it crashed. user error!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');//Here test is my database

var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', { name: String });

var kitty = new Cat({ name: 'Zildjian' });
kitty.save(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('meow');
  }
});
```